# Run rtsp streaming with SSL (using rtsps)

Tags: c#, rtsp, nimble

I am doing live streaming using rtsp like 'rtsp://{{CAMERAIP}}/axis-media/media.amp?resolution=352x240&compression=20' and its working fine.
Now I want to use secure rtsp like 'rtsps://{{CAMERAIP}}/axis-media/media.amp?resolution=352x240&compression=20', so anyone have any idea regarding this?

Comment: I'm looking for same thing and i've tried to search it on google but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node package node-rtsp-stream. Instead of piping through ws, implement a wss Websocket. This Websocket is then connected to the browser and display the content in a html canvas element.

My Setup:
 --> FFMPEG --wss--> Browser (with jsmpeg-module and html canvas)

Comment: Any help in getting node-rtsp-stream to use wss? I'm completely stuck trying to modify that library to accept wss rather than ws